# auto mount by service + service not mount the folder automatically

Tags: linux, centos, redhat-enterprise-linux, systemd, systemctl

we create the following service on redhat version 7.2

```
more nfsshare.mount
[Unit]
  Description=nfs mount script
  Requires=network-online.target
  After=network-online.service

[Mount]

  What=master1:/nfs
  Where=/nfsshare
  Options=noauto,user,rw,group
  Type=nfs
  TimeoutIdleSec=10

[Install]
  WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

after restart the service the mount point is mounted as should be

```
master1:/nfs             41932800 6559744  35373056  16% /nfsshare
```

now we umount the /nfsshare folder

```
umount /nfsshare
```

now we expecting  /nfsshare folder will be mounted again 
and service will automatically mout the folder

but nothing is happens and folder not mounted

where I am wrong here?

I also try

```
 more nfsshare.automount
[Unit]
  Description=nfs mount script
  Requires=network-online.target
  After=network-online.service

[Automount]
  What=master1:/nfs
  Where=/nfsshare
  Options=noauto,user,rw,group
  Type=nfs
  TimeoutIdleSec=10

[Install]
  WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

but this service even not mount the folder after restart